# Global.asax magic functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

When creating an ASP.NET Mvc project in Visual Studio, a `Global.asax` & `Global.asax.cs` will be created. In this .cs file you will find the standard `Application_Start` method.

My question is the following, how is this function called? because it is not a override. So my guess is that this method name is by convention. The same goes for the `Application_Error` method.

I want to know where these methods are hooked. Because I write those methods (not override them) I couldn't find any documentation on them in MSDN. (I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994a1482.aspx) page but it only tells you to hook to the `Error` event and shows a `Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` but not how the Event and the method are linked.)

```
//Magicly called at startup
protected void Application_Start() 
{
    //Omitted
}

//Magicly linked with the Error event
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Omitted
}
```

Comment: Its not really magic. The ASP.NET Pipeline hooks these up.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Can you point me to any documentation of this, so I can read up on it (/ maybe find other functions like it)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic. -Arthur C. Clarke

Comment: Here is a [list of available events](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/globalasax-events1) in case anyone, like myself, wonders where to find that information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't really magical.. the ASP.NET Pipeline wires all of this up.

You can [see the documentation regarding this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx#Overview).

Specifically you will be interested in the parts below:

> An `HttpApplication` object is assigned to the request.

Which consists of a list of events that are fired and in what order.

There are links all over that page (too many to contain here) that link off to various other pages with even more information.

---

> ASP.NET automatically binds application events to handlers in the
>   Global.asax file using the naming convention Application_event, such
>   as `Application_BeginRequest`. This is similar to the way that ASP.NET
>   page methods are automatically bound to events, such as the page's
>   `Page_Load` event.

<sup>*Source*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx</sup>

Comment: They are magical as the initial poster mentioned. They should have been abstract (mustoverride) and then enable to override them in the global.asax file. How someone remember the name and signature of these things???

Comment: @user1829319 I am not sure what your point is. The inability to remember an API or look up documentation does not make something magic.

Comment: Why should someone remember an Api? I should be able to override the function name when it is inheriting from base.

Comment: These are absolutely "magic". They are not concretely defined by an interface or in the base class. It's mystifying.

Comment: Even almost 3 years later @JohnHargrove I still don't consider them to be the definition of magical when there are resources to explain them.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead But the compiler won't tell you that the documentation on MSDN about how this automatic event hookup is performed has changed. If we had a proper base class for this we could rely on the compiler and other tools (e.g. Visual Studio) to help us out.

Comment: One could, of course, circumvent these concepts of the language entirely by just not using classes or interfaces anymore. In fact, I think you can just as well use only generics and reflection to come up with a system that kind of mimics the functionality. However, it will just be an obscure system that relies on either you seeing the source code, or the maintainer making sure to keep the docs up to date.

Answer (score 3):

To demystify the 'magic' of the accepted answer, the ASP.Net pipeline is automagically binding the `HttpApplication` events to the methods with the `Application_EventName` in the class. If (much like me) you would rather see the events explicitly bound to a handler these can be bound by overriding `HttpApplication.Init()` and Visual Studio will generate the handler method with the correct signature.

```
public override void Init()
{
  this.BeginRequest += MvcAppliction_BeginRequest;
}

private void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
}
```

There is an [example of this method of binding events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net itself creates it. Here is the flow as per MSDN -

- User requests an application resource from the Web server.
- ASP.NET receives the first request for the application.
- ASP.NET core objects are created for each request.
- An HttpApplication object is assigned to the request. In this step Global.asax will be processed and events will be associated automatically.
- The request is processed by the HttpApplication pipeline. In this step the HttpApplication Global events are raised.

[Here is the reference - ASP.Net Application Life Cycle.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx)

From the reference - ASP.NET automatically binds application events to handlers in the Global.asax file using the naming convention Application_event, such as Application_BeginRequest.